# How to fix app:mergeDebugResources error in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\ll\AndroidStudioProjects\Intro\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@9e59822.). Check logs for more details.

Help me fix this error